# ANTLR - StringTemplate - CamelCase

Tags: antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate, antlr4, stringtemplate-4

What is the best pattern **(language independent, for retargetable generation code)** to translate antlr token to camel case StringTemplate attribute in a tree conversion? Example: My DSL has MY_FIELD definition and in the StringTemplate output I need myField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parser you could set the text of the Token, and that should flow through to the StringTemplate.  Something like this grammar fragment should work:

`my=MY_FIELD { $my.setText("myField"); }`

Comment: ok friend!!! work ok in tree parsers with rules like

{$STRING.token.setText($STRING.text.toUpperCase());} -> (tree rewrite)

I will do it in a "java adapter walker", a walker for each target language..

thank you!!!